# fetching data shows double array on console.lg

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hi i am trying to fetch some data from a .json file to map them into a component. The code looks like this:

```
function App() {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/results.json')
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setResults(data);
      });
  }, []);

  console.log(results);
  return <Results results={results} />;
}
```

If i check the dev tools it shows me this:

```
[]
[]
(11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
(11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

why is the fetched array shown twice? have i done anything wrong, or how can i improve the code?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Do you use strict mode? React.StrictMode, makes it render twice @marc